# tecdoc WebService apache axis in .net client

Tags: .net, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, webservice-client

I am trying to use a Web Service generated on Apache Axis:

http://webservicepilot.tecdoc.net/pegasus-2-0/wsdl/TecdocToCatWL

```
VehicleManufacturers3Request req = new VehicleManufacturers3Request()
    {
        provider = 289,
        lang = "fr",
        carType ="1",
        evalFavor = false,
        favouredList = 1,
        countryGroupFlag = false,
        countriesCarSelection = "fr"
    };

getVehicleManufacturers3RequestBody requestBody = new getVehicleManufacturers3RequestBody(req);
getVehicleManufacturers3Request request = new getVehicleManufacturers3Request(requestBody);

TecdocToCat cat = new TecdocToCatClient();           

getVehicleManufacturers3Response response = cat.getVehicleManufacturers3(request);
```

Using fiddler I see that I get response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope 
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
    <getVehicleManufacturers3Response 
            xmlns="http://webservicepilot.tecdoc.net/pegasus-2-0/services/TecdocToCatWL">
        <getVehicleManufacturers3Return xmlns="">
            <data>
                <array>
                <array>
                    <manuId>609</manuId>
                    <manuName>AC</manuName>
                </array>
                <empty>false</empty>
            </data>
            <status>200</status>
            <statusText xsi:nil="true"/>
        </getVehicleManufacturers3Return>
    </getVehicleManufacturers3Response>
</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

But `response.Body` is empty.

Can somebody say what are the possbile problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using wrong version of the web service.

Comment: Do not forget to accept your own answer then. And maybe provide more information about the version of the web service.